# Polymer components loading individually making pages load slow

Tags: javascript, polymer, minify, predix

I have a polymer 2.0 project running on Predix.  Each time a new page loads you can watch in dev tools ad it loads all the polymer components 1 by 1.  I thought there was a was to minify this so it doesn't happen but I haven't been able to get it to work.

[[image: enter image description here]]